# Cannot assign to 'ImpactReceiver' because it is a 'method group'

Tags: c#

I've been working on a game so far and I've encountered a problem where it says I can't assign something due to it being a method group. It may have something to do that it wasn't in C# format or something. Thanks in advance

### Code

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if(other.relativeVelocity.magnitude > 3)
    {
        GameObject _exp = Instantiate(exp, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(_exp, 3);
        knockBack();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

void knockBack(){
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);

    foreach (Collider nearyby in colliders)
    {
        Rigidbody rigg = nearyby.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if(rigg != null)
        {
            rigg.AddExplosionForce(expForce, transform.position, radius);
        }

    }
}

void ImpactReceiver()
{


    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(explosionPosition, radius);
    foreach (var hit in colliders)
    {
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddExplosionForce(explosionPower, explosionPosition, radius, 3f);
        }
        else
        {
            var script = ImpactReceiver = hit.transform.GetComponent<ImpactReceiver>();
            if (script)
            {
                var dir = hit.transform.position - explosionPosition;
                var force = Mathf.Clamp(explosionPower / 3, 0, 15);
                script.AddImpact(dir, force);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you have a bool property named `ImpactReceiver`? I don't understand this line `var script = ImpactReceiver = hit.transform.GetComponent<ImpactReceiver>();`

Comment: @ClaudioRedi this is where i originally got the code and no I don't have a bool property named impact receiver  
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/242648/force-on-character-controller-knockback.html?_ga=2.269185975.737700034.1606497000-842140431.1604174449

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you are assigning to 'ImpactReceiver',

```
var script = ImpactReceiver = hit.transform.GetComponent<ImpactReceiver>();
```

it is a method.

```
void ImpactReceiver()
```

You cant do that. Sadly its not clear what you are trying to do so its hard to suggest what to do

Comment: im trying to follow this else however when i originally did it it gave a bunch of errors what im trying to do is apply force to my character when an object explodes                    
**original code**:{ // but if it's a character with ImpactReceiver, add the impact:
       var script: ImpactReceiver = hit.transform.GetComponent(ImpactReceiver);
       if (script){